# Error in open Database

Tags: android, database

UPDATE 4

this is my DBhelper class

```
      package com.example.dbtest;

       import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.InputStream;
       import java.io.OutputStream;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.Cursor;
       import android.database.SQLException;
      import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
       import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

       public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

String tablename;

Cursor ch;

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.dbtest/databases/";
public static String DB_NAME = "photodb";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private  Context myContext;



public DBhelper(Context cont) {
    super(cont, DB_NAME, null, 3);

}


public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist) {
        boolean flag = isOpen();
        if(flag==false){
        //this.getWritableDatabase();
        this.getReadableDatabase();

            //myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH,null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE|SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);


        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
    }

}



public boolean checkDataBase()
{
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}



private void copyDataBase() throws IOException  {


    InputStream myInput;

        myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("photodb");


    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;


    OutputStream myOutput;

        myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);



    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }


    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();


}

public boolean isOpen() {
    if (myDataBase != null)
        return myDataBase.isOpen();
    return false;
}


public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}



public void add_pics(String imagepath,String description,String location)

{


    myDataBase.execSQL("insert into photodetails values(null," + imagepath + ","
            + description + "," + location + ");");

}

}
```

ANd this is my MainActivity

```
       package com.example.dbtest;



     import java.io.IOException;

      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.Context;
       import android.view.Menu;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


DBhelper mydb;
Context cont;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mydb = new DBhelper(cont);

    try {
        mydb.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mydb.openDataBase();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

And My logcat Error is

09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dbtest/com.example.dbtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at com.example.dbtest.DBhelper.createDataBase(DBhelper.java:41)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at com.example.dbtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
09-02 18:43:26.052: E/AndroidRuntime(25477):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)

Comment: This is a suggestion. There are a few examples out there which you can easily download the example code and run. Here are the links:

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

But for me I prefer using the ORMLite. This small library comes with a lot of handy functions and less errors for developer. Please take a look at docs here:
http://ormlite.com/docs/ormlite.pdf

Examples:
http://ormlite.com/android/examples/

Comment: I know how to create database and run..For this particular code its not happening..The above code is not wrong

Comment: Can you try remove "/data" from your path "/data/data/"? In your error it shown:

`09-02 15:37:05.010: E/SQLiteDatabase(29919): Failed to open database '/data  /data/com.cdotsys.photoapp/databases/photodb'.`

There is a space between first "/data" and second "/data".

Comment: no help..still its giving error..I am using samsung s2 for device testing

Comment: At the statup of your application at that time you have to call creatDatabase() method.

Comment: I am doing exactly the same..i am calling createdatabase method from my onCreate activity of another class.And its showing error on the line this.getwritabledatabse..

and the error is 09-02 17:31:28.500: E/AndroidRuntime(17045):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
09-02 17:31:28.500: E/AndroidRuntime(17045):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
public boolean checkDataBase()
{
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

Instead of

```
private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

you are getting following exception `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)`

because you are trying to open more than one instances of `SQLiteDatabase`. Just make sure only one instance is open at a time. You can implement `DBhelper` using `Singelton` pattern.
For that you can refer [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html)

Comment: Although after using ur code the number of error got reduced..but still its throwing the error in the line this.getRedableDatabase()

Comment: I Have updated the code and logcat..Please check..And Please help

Comment: I think, you are trying to open the database when it is already opened. You need to close the db before, if you want to use this.getRedableDatabase()

Comment: No matter what i do its still throwing the error !!! and yes i have implemented the dbhelper class synchronously..Also i have tried 
mydatabase.openorcreatedatabase method..But still no use :(

Comment: show the code for activity where you are trying to open database.

Comment: **If i use this line
                    myDataBase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH, null);
                    instead of 
                    this.getWritableDatabase()
                    I am getting Could Not Open Database Error**

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
   SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE|SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
```

set permission in manifest file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also you need to create metadata table in sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')
```

and

```
INSERT INTO "android_metadata" VALUES ('en_US')
```

Comment: where i have to write 
CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')

and

INSERT INTO "android_metadata" VALUES ('en_US') ????

Comment: And u are suggesting instead of using this.getWritableDatabase() i can use 

SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE|SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS)??

Comment: I am posting a fresh small code..please check..and let me know where i am wrong